# Extraer datos de Flashcore

Tags: python, pandas, scraping

No tengo mucha idea de programar en Python. Tengo un problema. Cuando trato de extraer datos de *Flashcore* me aparece el siguiente error:

`list index out of range.`

Por lo que he visto, el tamaño de `times` es distinto al de `set1` pero no sé cómo arreglarlo para que las dos columnas tengan el mismo tamaño.
¿Alguien sabe? Muchas gracias.

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd 


url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/table-tennis/others-men/tt-star-series/results/'

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
async def get_scores():
    r = await asession.get(url)
    await r.html.arender()
    return r

results = asession.run(get_scores)
results = results[0]


times = results.html.find("div.event__time")
home_players = results.html.find("div.event__participant.event__participant--home") 
scores_home = results.html.find('div > div.event__score.event__score--home')
scores_home_set1 = results.html.find('div > div.event__part.event__part--home.event__part--1')


dict_res = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(len(times)):
        dict_res['times'].append(times[i].text)
        dict_res['home_players'].append(home_players[i].text)
        dict_res['scores_home'].append(scores_home[i].text)
        dict_res['set1'].append(scores_home_set1[i].text)
        
df_res = pd.DataFrame(dict_res)
df_res.to_csv('ttstar.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer scraping hay formas con menos código que te pueden resultar útiles. Te dejo un ejemplo usando selenium y voy colocando comentarios para guiarte:

```
from selenium import webdriver #Llamamos a webdriver de selenium. Al final te dejo una liga para saber más acerca de Selenium

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver') #Arrancamos firefox (puedes usar Chrome si te es más cómodo). OJO: en mi caso uso mac por eso está implícito el path del driver
url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/table-tennis/others-men/tt-star-series/results/'
driver.get(url) #Llamamos a tu página
```

A diferencia como tu lo hacías, llamo toda la información en un solo paso, solo debes encontrar el elemento que se repite dentro del html, en este caso noté que los resultados de cada match se guardan dentro de la `class event__match` por lo tanto hago uso de ella

```
data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('event__match')
```

Extraemos la info de selenium y la insertamos en un `list`

```
data_clean = [] #Generamos un list donde depositaremos la info limpia
for i in range(len(data)): #Para recorrer todos los resultados de los match
    data_clean.append(data[i].text) #Ingresamos los datos a nuestro nuevo list
```

Para finalizar reemplazamos los caracteres `\n` que salen por un pipe `|`, cabe mencionar que puedes reemplazarlo por lo que quieras y te funcione. Puede ser por comas para que se arme un buen .csv

```
data_clean = [x.replace("\n", "|") for x in data_clean]
```

El resultado es:

```
print(data_clean)

['06.10. 08:40|Cifuentes H. (Arg)|Tregler T. (Cze)|3|0|14|12|12|10|12|10',
 '06.10. 08:15|Seibert J. (Cze)|Putuntica A. (Mda)|0|3|7|11|4|11|9|11',
 '06.10. 07:40|Tregler T. (Cze)|Putuntica A. (Mda)|3|2|11|6|13|11|6|11|9|11|11|9',
 '06.10. 07:15|Cifuentes H. (Arg)|Seibert J. (Cze)|3|0|11|7|11|3|11|7',...
```

[image: Resultados Tennis Match]
No puse todos los resultados porque me salen más de 121.

El código completo luciría así:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/table-tennis/others-men/tt-star-series/results/'
driver.get(url)

data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('event__match')
data_clean = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    data_clean.append(data[i].text)

data_clean = [x.replace("\n", "|") for x in data_clean]
data_clean
```

Mas info acerca de **Selenium Webdriver**: https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @AlbertoCastillo Hay tantas formas de programar que a veces no sabe uno qué le está fallando. Me estaba rompiendo la cabeza y no conseguía llegar a ningún lado. Me ha sido realmente útil. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Al código completo, le falta añadirle la fila que me explicaste antes. Por si quieres añadirla. Saludos ´´´ data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('event__match')´´´

Comment: @EnriqueRamirezMoreno agradezco la observación, he corregido el error. Me alegro que el código te funcione. ¡Mucho éxito!